# Getting last day of the month in a given string date

Tags: java, date, calendar

My input string date is as below:

```
String date = "1/13/2012";
```

I am getting the month as below:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(convertedDate);
```

But how do I get the last calendar day of the month in a given String date?

E.g.: for a String `"1/13/2012"` the output must be `"1/31/2012"`.

Comment: FYI, the `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. See Answers such as [the one by Zeeshan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31720245/642706) and [the one by Krishna](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40689365/642706) for examples of using `LocalDate` and other modern date-time classes.

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624504/1700321).

Answer (score 200, accepted):

#### Java 8 and above.

By using `convertedDate.getMonth().length(convertedDate.isLeapYear())` where `convertedDate` is an instance of `LocalDate`.

```
String date = "1/13/2012";
LocalDate convertedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy"));
convertedDate = convertedDate.withDayOfMonth(
                                convertedDate.getMonth().length(convertedDate.isLeapYear()));
```

#### Java 7 and below.

By using `getActualMaximum` method of `java.util.Calendar`:

```
String date = "1/13/2012";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(convertedDate);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: How to use this given "1/13/2012"?

Comment: Call `setTime` on Calendar.

Comment: The solution for Java 8 using `TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()` suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40689365/466862 is simpler.

Answer (score 32):

This looks like your needs:

http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.de/2010/08/get-last-day-of-month-date-object-in.html

code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;  
import java.text.DateFormat;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Calendar;  
import java.util.Date;  

//Java 1.4+ Compatible  
//  
// The following example code demonstrates how to get  
// a Date object representing the last day of the month  
// relative to a given Date object.  

public class GetLastDayOfMonth {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Date today = new Date();  

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
        calendar.setTime(today);  

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

        Date lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();  

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
        System.out.println("Today            : " + sdf.format(today));  
        System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + sdf.format(lastDayOfMonth));  
    }  

}
```

Output:

```
Today            : 2010-08-03  
Last Day of Month: 2010-08-31
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: what is that  calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);   ?

Comment: @gumuruh It’s one of very many peculiarities with the outdated `Calendar` class that caused that class to be abandoned nearly 10 years ago now. As the other comment suggests, forget about that class and use java..time instead.

Answer (score 29):

By using java 8 java.time.LocalDate

```
String date = "1/13/2012";
LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yyyy"))
       .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: Actually I used TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()

Comment: I see now. How about adding some discussion or explanation too to make a better Answer? For example, mention the `TemporalAdjuster` interface and the `TemporalAdjusters` class for implementations. Stack Overflow is intended to be more than a snippet-library. And, thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth                            // Represent the year and month, without a date and without a time zone.
.from(                               // Extract the year and month from a `LocalDate` (a year-month-day). 
    LocalDate                        // Represent a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone.
    .parse(                          // Get a date from an input string.        
        "1/13/2012" ,                // Poor choice of format for a date. Educate the source of your data about the standard ISO 8601 formats to be used when exchanging date-time values as text.
        DateTimeFormatter            // Specify a formatting pattern by which to parse the input string.
        .ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu" )     // Match the pattern of your input.
    )                                // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
)                                    // Returns a `YearMonth` object.
.atEndOfMonth()                      // Determines the last day of the month for that particular year-month, and returns a `LocalDate` object.
.toString()                          // Generate text representing the value of that `LocalDate` object using standard ISO 8601 format.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/a2TIne).

> 2012-01-31

## `YearMonth`

The `YearMonth` class makes this easy. The `atEndOfMonth` method returns a `LocalDate`. Leap year in February is accounted for.

First define a formatting pattern to match your string input.

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu" ) ;

Use that formatter to get a `LocalDate` from the string input.

```
String s = "1/13/2012" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1/13/2012" , f ) ;
```

Then extract a `YearMonth` object.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Ask that `YearMonth` to determine the last day of its month in that year, accounting for [Leap Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) in February.

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth() ;
```

Generate text representing that date, in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = endOfMonth.toString() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Just a detail here, compared to `LocalDate.with`, it requires to instantiate a `YearMonth` from the `LocalDate` then rebuild the `LocalDate` at the end of the month, so it create one more instance.

Comment: @AxelH I don’t understand your comment. All of the *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), as part of their design to be thread-safe and to act as value objects. `LocalDate::with` always provides a new instance, just like `LocalDate::plus`, `LocalDate::minus`, and so on. Also, with modern JVMs, there is no need to be shy about creating objects.

Comment: Just count the number of instance created to get the last day. Using `LocalDate.with` only requires one new instance, using your solution requires on more, the  `YearMonth` used. It is just a detail.

Answer (score 10):

**Java 8 and above:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;

static int lastDayOfMonth(int Y, int M) {
    return LocalDate.of(Y, M, 1).getMonth().length(Year.of(Y).isLeap());
}
```

**subject to Basil Bourque's comment**

```
import java.time.YearMonth;

int lastDayOfMonth = YearMonth.of(Y, M).lengthOfMonth();
```

Comment: The Question requires parsing a string. You did  not address that here.

Comment: This code could be simplified by using [`YearMonth::lengthOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#lengthOfMonth--)

Comment: By convention, Java variables are named with first letter being lowercase.

Answer (score 7):

> With Java 8 `DateTime` / `LocalDateTime` :

```
String dateString = "01/13/2012";
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US); 
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormat);       
ValueRange range = date.range(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Long max = range.getMaximum();
LocalDate newDate = date.withDayOfMonth(max.intValue());
System.out.println(newDate);
```

> OR

```
String dateString = "01/13/2012";
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US); 
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormat);
LocalDate newDate = date.withDayOfMonth(date.getMonth().length(date.isLeapYear()));
System.out.println(newDate);
```

Output:

```
2012-01-31
```

> `LocalDateTime` should be used instead of `LocalDate` if you have time information in your date string . I.E. `2015/07/22 16:49`

Comment: Indeed very informative, alternatively finding the maximum day of the month can also be done using the following code.     `LocalDate.now().getMonth().maxLength()`

Comment: Another variation is the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class. `LocalDate endOfMonth = YearMonth.from( myLocalDate ).atEndOfMonth() ;`

Comment: This `date.withDayOfMonth(date.getMonth().maxLength())` will fail for February. See [accepted and updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13624504/1700321) for  solution.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer taking hint from your's.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to construt a new `GregorianCalendar` instance, see below:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 5, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println("Date : " + sdf.format(date));
```

Output:

```
Date : 2013-05-31
```

Attention:

> month the value used to set the MONTH calendar field in the calendar. Month value is 0-based e.g. 0 for January.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get last day of the month

```
public static String getLastDayOfTheMonth(String date) {
        String lastDayOfTheMonth = "";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try{
        java.util.Date dt= formatter.parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
        calendar.setTime(dt);  

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

        java.util.Date lastDay = calendar.getTime();  

        lastDayOfTheMonth = formatter.format(lastDay);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lastDayOfTheMonth;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            String givenStringDate ="07/16/2020";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        java.util.Date convertedUtillDate;
            /*
             * If your output requirement is in LocalDate format use below snippet
             * 
             */
            LocalDate localDate =LocalDate.parse(givenStringDate, formatter);
            LocalDate localDateLastDayOfMonth = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());

            /*
             * If your output requirement is in Calendar format use below snippet
             * 
             */
            convertedUtillDate = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            Calendar calendarLastDayOfMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarLastDayOfMonth.setTime(convertedUtillDate);
            int lastDate = calendarLastDayOfMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
            calendarLastDayOfMonth.set(Calendar.DATE, lastDate);
```

Tested in Java 1.8.
I hope this will help some one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple and fastest way is

```
public static int getLastDayOf(int month, int year) {
    switch (month) {
        case Calendar.APRIL:
        case Calendar.JUNE:
        case Calendar.SEPTEMBER:
        case Calendar.NOVEMBER:
            return 30;
        case Calendar.FEBRUARY:
            if (year % 4 == 0) {
                return 29;
            }
            return 28;
        default:
            return 31;
    }
}
```

Since these values are constant universally!

Comment: Not recommended. (1) Don’t use `Calendar`, it’s a long outdated and confusingly designed class. (2) Don’t implement your own date logic. It’s error-prone and much better left to the standard library, in this case to either the `LocalDate` or the `YearMonth` class. Also your code is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I am generating the current Date using the now method. And then I am using TemporalAdjusters to get the final date of the month. I can also pass a custom date to get the work done.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [plusMonths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-) and [minusDays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays-long-) methods in Java 8:

```
// Parse your date into a LocalDate
LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse("1/13/2012", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy"));

// We only care about its year and month, set the date to first date of that month
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(parsed.getYear(), parsed.getMonth(), 1);

// Add one month, subtract one day 
System.out.println(localDate.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1)); // 2012-01-31
```

Comment: The [existing similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40689365/642706) is simpler than this.

Answer (score -1):

Use `GregorianCalendar`. Set the date of the object, and then use `getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_IN_MONTH)`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29 (but it was the same in Java 1.4)

Comment: How to use this given "1/13/2012"?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String getLastDayOfMonth(int year, int month) throws Exception{
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date = sdf.parse(year+"-"+(month<10?("0"+month):month)+"-01");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    Date lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();

    return sdf.format(lastDayOfMonth);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 1));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 3));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 4));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 5));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 6));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 7));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 8));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 9));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 10));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 11));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 12));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2018, 1));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2018, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2018, 3));

    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2010, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2011, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2012, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2013, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2014, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2015, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2016, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2017, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2018, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2019, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2020, 2));
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: " + getLastDayOfMonth(2021, 2));
}
```

**output:**

> Last Day of Month: 2017-01-31
>  Last Day of Month: 2017-02-28
>   Last Day of Month: 2017-03-31
>  Last Day of Month: 2017-04-30
>   Last Day of Month: 2017-05-31
>  Last Day of Month: 2017-06-30
>   Last Day of Month: 2017-07-31
>  Last Day of Month: 2017-08-31
>   Last Day of Month: 2017-09-30
>  Last Day of Month: 2017-10-31
>   Last Day of Month: 2017-11-30
>  Last Day of Month: 2017-12-31
>   Last Day of Month: 2018-01-31
>  Last Day of Month: 2018-02-28
>   Last Day of Month: 2018-03-31
>  Last Day of Month: 2010-02-28
>   Last Day of Month: 2011-02-28
>  Last Day of Month: 2012-02-29
>   Last Day of Month: 2013-02-28
>  Last Day of Month: 2014-02-28
>   Last Day of Month: 2015-02-28
>  Last Day of Month: 2016-02-29
>   Last Day of Month: 2017-02-28
>  Last Day of Month: 2018-02-28
>   Last Day of Month: 2019-02-28
>  Last Day of Month: 2020-02-29
>   Last Day of Month: 2021-02-28

Comment: This code uses troublesome old date-time classes that have been legacy for years, supplanted by the java.time classes. This Answer is ill-advised.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the solution is Tested and works

```
public static Date toDate(String date, String DATE_FORMAT) {
    Date dt = null;
    try {
        String[] d = date.split(" ");
        String[] f = DATE_FORMAT.split(" ");
        if (d.length > 1) {
            if(f.length > 1) {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
                df.setLenient(false);
                dt = df.parse(date);
            }
            else
            {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(f[0]);
                df.setLenient(false);
                dt = df.parse(date);
            }
        } else {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(f[0]);
            df.setLenient(false);
            dt = df.parse(date);
        }
        return dt;
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        return null;
    }
}

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
String StartDate = "05/01/2021";
Calendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar();
Date convertedDate = toDate(StartDate, "MM/dd/yyyy");
endDate.setTime(convertedDate);
endDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
endDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
endDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
String EndDate = dateFormatter.format(endDate.getTime());
```

**OutOut: 05/31/2021**

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Also this is 37 lines of code where some of the other answers have 3 to 10 lines of code, and you are not explaining anything that we might gain from your longer code.

Comment: so where is your New and Smart updated answer to this question?

Comment: Updated, modern and smart answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40689365/5772882), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720245/5772882), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54080554/5772882), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54074534/5772882) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62021961/5772882). Plus the accepted answer. No need for me to repeat what they already say.

Comment: (My answer to a similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64359132/5772882), but not the same question.)

Comment: None of Answer by you... very funny... except last one amd i don see any solution here... so far i guess, people needs codes of solutions not Article... Don mind pls...

Comment: I preach the exact opposite. People who need code should not go to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is the place for people who want to learn (we all should, I do). And no one needs your 37 lines of code. It uses outdated classes, we don't know what it does, presumably something that has already been obtained in 10 good lines or lesd.

Answer (score -2):

Works fine for me with this

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone());
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);  
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);  
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 
    cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. See the [correct Answer by Sheehan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720245/642706) and its Comments.

Answer (score -3):

I use this one-liner on my JasperServer Reports:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(new java.util.Date().format('yyyy') + "-" + (new Integer (new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(new Date()))+1) + "-01")-1)
```

Doesn't look nice but works for me. Basically it's adding 1 to the current month, get the first day of that month and subtract one day.