# Get last day of Month

Tags: java, date, calendar

For getting last date of month I have written this function

```
/**
 * @param month integer value of month
 * @param year integer value of month
 * @return last day of month in MM/dd/YYYY format
 */
private static String getDate(int month, int year) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // passing month-1 because 0-->jan, 1-->feb... 11-->dec
    calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    return DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
}
```

for all the inputs its working fine with one exception when the month is December, i.e. getDate(12, 2012) returns 12/31/2013 but it should return 12/31/2012.
Please explain the behavior and solution too.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624442/getting-last-day-of-the-month-in-given-string-date .It might help you.

Comment: I would advise to change the name of the function to something for descriptive like `getLastDayOfMonth`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting last day of the month in given string date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624442/getting-last-day-of-the-month-in-given-string-date)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `YYYY` to `yyyy`

```
DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

`YYYY` is wrong `dateformat`

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.of( 2016 , 6 )
         .atEndOfMonth()
         .toString()
```

> 2016-06-30

## java.time

Very easy with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. [Back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `YearMonth`

Use the handy [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

Tip:  Pass objects of this class around your code base rather than mere integers to benefit from type-safety, guaranteed valid values, and more self-documenting code.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( 2016 , 6 );
```

…or…

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( 2016 , Month.JUNE );
```

### `LocalDate`

Then ask for the last day of that month, represented by [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth();
```

> 2016-06-30

### Strings

The result of [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) you see above, where a String was generated using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatting. You can use other formatting.

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class can automatically translate to a human language and apply cultural norms to issues such as period versus comma or the ordering of year-month-day parts.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.US );  // Re-assign JVM’s current default Locale that was implicitly applied to the formatter.
String output = localDate.format( formatter );
```

The [`Locale.US`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US) gives us a month/day/year format. You can also specify an explicit pattern by calling [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-).

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer considering the new Java 8.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);  
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), it's more simple :

```
private static String getLastDayOfMonth(int month, int year) {
    LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = new LocalDate(year, month, 1).dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
    return lastDayOfMonth.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private static String getDate(int month, int year) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));

    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With Java 8 DateTime / LocalDateTime :

private static String getDate(int month, int year) {        
    Month monthObj = Month.of(month);       
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, monthObj.maxLength());
    return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US));
}
```

Comment: [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class is a better fit to the problem, and simpler. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38109343/642706).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get last day of the month

```
public static String getLastDayOfTheMonth(String date) {
        String lastDayOfTheMonth = "";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try{
        java.util.Date dt= formatter.parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
        calendar.setTime(dt);  

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);  

        java.util.Date lastDay = calendar.getTime();  

        lastDayOfTheMonth = formatter.format(lastDay);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lastDayOfTheMonth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this

```
private static String getDate(int month, int year)
{
    Calendar dateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateCal.set(year, month, 2);
    int maxDay = dateCal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    String pattern = "MMMM";
    SimpleDateFormat obDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    String monthName = obDateFormat.format(dateCal.getTime());

    return "Last date of " + monthName + " " + year + " : " + maxDay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you considering leap year as well here? if not then you can try below code:

```
public static Date calculateMonthEndDate(int month, int year) {
    int[] daysInAMonth = { 29, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    int day = daysInAMonth[month];
    boolean isLeapYear = new GregorianCalendar().isLeapYear(year);

    if (isLeapYear && month == 2) {
        day++;
    }
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day);
    Date monthEndDate = new Date(gc.getTime().getTime());
    return monthEndDate;
}
```

Comment: This code uses troublesome old legacy classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.