# Is it the last day of the month?

Tags: java, date

What I want to happen - if the date (that is given from the parameters) is equal to the last day of the month, I want the cost to be increased by 10%. I.e if dayOfTravel = last day of the month

```
  public static double ReturnJourneyCost(int journeyID, int dayOfTravel, int monthOfTravel, int yearOfTravel){

    Cost = Double.parseDouble(XMLLoad.load(journeyID, 3));
    return Cost;

}
```

Comment: What's the issue? I don't an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: On a side note, Java naming conventions recommend method names start with lower case

Comment: @Averroes, even for `static` methods?

Comment: Worst case add a day, see if the month changed...

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko AFAIK yes

Comment: I want it to do this - if the last day of the month is equal to dayOfTravel then it adds 10% to the Cost variable. @RohitJain

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the first day of the current week and month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937086/how-to-get-the-first-day-of-the-current-week-and-month). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4786169/642706). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8997228/642706). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9397203/642706). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19488658/642706). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13624442/642706).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using old JDK-stuff the answer might look like:

```
public static boolean isLastDayOfMonth(int year, int month, int day) {
  GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day);
  gcal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
  return (gcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1);
}
```

In Java 8 (better because it avoids any implicit reference to system timezone):

```
public static boolean isLastDayOfMonth(int year, int month, int day) {
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
  return date.lengthOfMonth() == day;
}
```

Comment: The Java 8 solution is very clearly to be preferred. When this answer was written 8 years ago, Java 8 was brand new. Today no one should use `GregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, using [`GregorianCalendar.getActualMaximum()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29), will do the trick:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearOfTravel);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfTravel); // warning: 0-based!
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfTravel);

int daysInThisMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if (daysInThisMonth == dayOfTravel)
{
    // increase cost by 10%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some custom code...

```
public boolean isLastDay(Date date) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.setTime(date);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);

    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    return c.get(Calendar.MONTH) != now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == monthOfTravel && 
&& calendar.ger(Calendar.YEAR) == yearOfTravel && calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == dayOfTravel) {
//...
}
```