# How to get the last date of given month and year in java

Tags: java, date

I have the date with the following format for user given months and year  e.g. 02/15 `MM/yy` format. I want to find last date of the month if it is leap year it should return 29 else not need to return 28. Can anybody tell how to do?

Comment: [getting last day of the month in given string date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13624442/1700321).

Comment: Note that the time format you actually want to use is: MM/yy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Java 8** you can do the following:

```
private static final String DATE_PATTERN = "MM/yy";

public int getLastDayOfMonth(String dateString) {
    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN);
    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(dateString, pattern);
    LocalDate date = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth();
    return date.lengthOfMonth();
}
```

In **earlier versions of Java** you can:

```
public int getLastDayOfMonth(String dateString) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateString));
    return calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```