# Is there a method to add months to a date fetching the below expected

Tags: java, datetime

Is there a mechanism or a method in Joda Time itself/or some other API through which i can achieve the same.???
Please suggest?

Input Date: 2018-04-30

Used Joda Time like this gives output: 2018-05-30

Expected Date : 2018-05-31

**Edited Again**
Want to know if it will be alright to say and do like this meaning

> if the input date is the last date(will use the algos shared) then
>   fetch the last date of the next month and
>
> else if input date is anything else then use plusMonths method

right??

```java
String startDate = "2018-04-30";
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(startDate, DateTimeZone.UTC);

int repeatEvery = 1;
int numOfPayments = 2;
String endDate = startDateTime.plusMonths(repeatEvery * (numOfPayments-1)).toString();
System.out.println(endDate);
```

Comment: What exectly you want to achieve? Do you want to calculate the Date of the last payment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting last day of the month in a given string date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624442/getting-last-day-of-the-month-in-a-given-string-date)

Comment: Why would you expect to get the 31st of May when you add a month to the 30th of April? In general, for "Year Y, Month M, day D" + 1 month, I'd expect the result to be "Year Y, Month M+1, Day D" whenever that's valid.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know i also thought the same thing but i suppose the BA's want it as asked above

Comment: @StefanWendelmann yes you are right... i want to calculate the end date of a StandingInstructions (when in input i am given startDate, repeatEvery. repeatFrequency)   **ex. startDate = "30-04-2019" and repeatEvery = "1" and repeatFreq = "MONTHLY"** meaning payments to be done after every 1month starting from startDate so the last date expected by bank is "31-05-2019" but the output that i am getting is "30-05-2019"

Comment: I would suggest that's a conversation you need to have with the BAs then.

Comment: @JonSkeet already had... still they are wanting it this way

Comment: Then you need to get *precise* requirements from them. If the input date was 2018-04-29, what would they want the result to be, for example?

Comment: For 2018-04-29 then they want the next date to be -> 2018-05-29 if the next SI fre quency set by end user is 1 month since the prev payments date was not the last date of the month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Java Time API, it is quite simple to get the last day of a month using a `TemporalAdjuster`, the API come with some already define, like `TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()`.

So here is a simple example on how to get the last day of the next month (based on today).

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now()
    .plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()));
```

This is pretty verbose to be understandable I believe.

To parse the String into a `LocalDate`. Simply replace `now()` by `parse()` like :

```
LocalDate.parse("2019-05-03", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

Using :

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
```

*This is actually already [an answer in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40689365/4391450) proposed, just need to scoll a bit to find it. It lakes some visibility !!*

Comment: OP seems to use joda time though

Comment: @Lino I took advantage of "_Joda Time itself/or some other API_" ;) I honesty never used the JodaTime. I always fight the Calendar and now I am a disciple of the `java.time`. I would guess that in `Joda`, you could simply set to the first day of the next month and retrieve one day to get to the last day of the previous month. (an old trick of the `Calendar` ;) )

Comment: I think java.time was greatly inspired by joda.time. They're not very different, but I still prefer the former though.

Comment: @Lino inspired but I think I have read that some are still using Joda to keep some interesting feature that were not included in java.time. So it might be even simpler than this ;)

Comment: @AxelH Thank you so much.. You saved so much of my effort.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this by the Calendar

```java
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String startDate = "2018-04-30";

    int repeatEvery = 1;
    int numOfPayments = 2;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(startDate));
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, repeatEvery * (numOfPayments - 1));
    System.out.println("intRes: "+sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    String endDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    System.out.println(endDate);
```

**out**:

intRes: 2018-05-30

2018-06-01

I dont know why this is giving me the 2018-06-01 ?

Comment: I don't believe the usage of `Calendar`, today, is still a good thing except in legacy code of course..

Comment: I agree with @AxelH, the old `Date` api should be abandoned. And the newer `java.time` api should be used instead