# How do I set an alarm to go off on the last day of every month?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alarms, android-calendar

So I would like to have an alarm that goes off on the last day of every month at 11:59 PM. This is the code that I have for that:

```
val monthlyCal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
monthlyCal[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 23
monthlyCal[Calendar.MINUTE] = 59
monthlyCal[Calendar.SECOND] = 59
monthlyCal[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0
monthlyCal[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
val monthlyIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this@MainActivity,
    0,
    Intent(this, MonthlyBroadcastReceiver::class.java),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
val monthlyAm: AlarmManager = this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
monthlyAm.setInexactRepeating(
    AlarmManager.RTC,
    monthlyCal.timeInMillis,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
    monthlyIntent
)
```

Am I doing this correctly? Can someone please verify?

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624442/getting-last-day-of-the-month-in-a-given-string-date

Comment: @Azhagthott That post doesn't even help me.