# How can I write a method that returns the first and last day of a passed month and year?

Tags: java, date, inheritance, calendar

The `dateTimeInherit` class is an inherited class from `dateTimeAbstract` so it must use the `daysOfAnyMonth` method. I was thinking of using some classes from the `YearMonth` and `LocalDate` classes but was not sure where to go from there.

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Driver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
      DateTimeInherit dateTimeInherit = new DateTimeInherit();
        
         /**
         * From the given line of codes you have to identify the class name and necessary 
         constructors/methods
         * In the following method, the first parameter is the month and the second parameter is the 
         year.
         * We are going to print the first day and the last day (day of the week) of any given month of 
         the year.
         * Output format: for (4, 2020):
         * In the year 2020, for the 4th month: the first day is WEDNESDAY and the last day is 
         THURSDAY       
         */     
        
        dateTimeInherit.daysOfAnyMonth(9, 2020);
        dateTimeInherit.daysOfAnyMonth(10, 2020);
        dateTimeInherit.daysOfAnyMonth(12, 2020);
        System.out.print("\n");




public abstract class DateTimeAbstract 
{
abstract void daysOfAnyMonth(int monthOfYear, int theYear);
}

import java.util.Calendar;
public class DateTimeInherit extends DateTimeAbstract 
{
  // Method that needs to be written
}
```

Comment: Are you _required_ to use obsolete `Calendar` class when implementing this task?  Or you can use newer [Java Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)?

Comment: @Alex Rudenko No I can use Java Time API, I was just thinking of using the Calendar class

Comment: @acc13241 - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree with you to use `YearMonth` and `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Pass your month number and year to `YearMonth.of(int, int)`. See the link below for the documentation. Remember to swap the arguments: the year goes first. Store the obtained `YearMonth` object into a variable. Use its `atDay` and `atEndOfMonth` methods for obtaining the first and the last day of the month as `LocalDate` objects. In turn use `LocalDate.getDayOfWeek()` for getting the day of the week.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Documentation:

  - [`YearMonth.of(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#of-int-int-)
  - [`YearMonth.atDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atDay-int-)
  - [`YearMonth.atEndOfMonth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth--)
  - [`LocalDate.getDayOfWeek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--)

Answer (score 0):

You could create instance of `LocalDate` and use its methods `withDayOfMonth / lengthOfMonth`:

```java
static void daysOfMonth(int month, int year) {
    LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
        
    LocalDate lastDay = firstDay.withDayOfMonth(firstDay.lengthOfMonth());
        
    System.out.printf("first day is: %s, last day is: %s", firstDay.getDayOfWeek(), lastDay.getDayOfWeek());
}
```

test:

```java
daysOfMonth(9, 2020);
```

prints:

```
first day is: TUESDAY, last day is: WEDNESDAY
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do it using date-time API. I suggest you use the [modern date-time and their corresponding formatting API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        daysOfAnyMonth(9, 2020);
        daysOfAnyMonth(10, 2020);
        daysOfAnyMonth(12, 2020);
    }

    static void daysOfAnyMonth(int month, int year) {
        LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
        LocalDate lastDate = firstDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("First day of the month: " + firstDate.getDayOfWeek() + ", Last day of the month: "
                + lastDate.getDayOfWeek());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
First day of the month: TUESDAY, Last day of the month: WEDNESDAY
First day of the month: THURSDAY, Last day of the month: SATURDAY
First day of the month: TUESDAY, Last day of the month: THURSDAY
```

The following table summarizes the [Method Naming Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) of the modern date-time API:

[image]

**Note:** If you need to print the weekday name in the proper case, you can do so as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        daysOfAnyMonth(9, 2020);
        daysOfAnyMonth(10, 2020);
        daysOfAnyMonth(12, 2020);
    }

    static void daysOfAnyMonth(int month, int year) {
        LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
        LocalDate lastDate = firstDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("First day of the month: "
                + firstDate.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH) + ", Last day of the month: "
                + lastDate.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));

        // Alternatively: By using DateTimeFormatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println("First day of the month: " + firstDate.format(formatter) + ", Last day of the month: "
                + lastDate.format(formatter));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
First day of the month: Tuesday, Last day of the month: Wednesday
First day of the month: Tuesday, Last day of the month: Wednesday

First day of the month: Thursday, Last day of the month: Saturday
First day of the month: Thursday, Last day of the month: Saturday

First day of the month: Tuesday, Last day of the month: Thursday
First day of the month: Tuesday, Last day of the month: Thursday
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.